# r shiny table not rendering html

Tags: r, shiny

I'm creating a table using renderTable but the HTML inside the table is not rendering:

[image: table not rendering]

This is the code snipit of interest:

```
if (is.null(Compare_Count) || is.na(Compare_Count) || length(Compare_Count) == 0L ) {
          CT_Table[i, 3] <- HTML("<i class='icon-arrow-up'></i>")
        } else if (CT_Table[i, 2] > Compare_Count) {
          CT_Table[i, 3] <- print(tags$i(class='icon-arrow-up', style="text-color: green"), quote = FALSE)
}
```

Neither `HTML`, `paste`, or `c` work.

How can I get the arrows to show?

Thanks!

---

`server.r`: [Note, this is an example. The code is not complete, brackets may be mismatched, etc. Not important to the question.]

```
output$example <- renderTable(include.rownames=FALSE,{
 CT_Table <- count(Canidates,vars=c("Name"))
 CT_Table <- CT_Table[order(CT_Table["Recent Reviews: "], decreasing=T),]
    for (i in 1:nrow(CT_Table)) {
      Compare_Name <- paste(CT_Table$Product[i])
      Compare_Count <- Can_trend[Can_trend$Name == Compare_Name, 2]
        if (is.null(Compare_Count) || is.na(Compare_Count) || length(Compare_Count) == 0L ) 
{
          CT_Table[i, 3] <- HTML("<i class='icon-arrow-up'></i>")
        } else if (CT_Table[i, 2] > Compare_Count) {
          CT_Table[i, 3] <- tags$i(class='icon-arrow-up', style="text-color: green")
        } else if (CT_Table[i, 2] < Compare_Count) {
          CT_Table[i, 3] <- tags$i(class='icon-arrow-down', style="text-color: red")
        } else if (CT_Table[i, 2] == Compare_Count) {
          CT_Table[i, 3] <- tags$i(class='icon-minus', style="text-color: yellow")
        }
     }
  }
 CT_Table
})
```

`ui.r` is just a simple call to `tableOutput` or `htmlOutput`, but neither renders the html pasted into the column.

Comment: Could you provide minimal but complete `ui.R` and `server.R` files ?

Comment: I have updated the question with a more complete code example; the file is a few thousand lines long, so I'm trying to only paste in whats necessary. Please let me know if I left anything out, and thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This was fixed with `sanitize.text.function = function(x) x`;

it needs to be included like this:

```
output$example <- renderTable({
   table <- someTable_Data_here
   table
}, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
```

This is the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/ramnathv/f476dd3751e672a96801)

---

also, a note,

I have noticed that you can call `xtable` inside the `renderTable` function, and it will properly render the table.

**BUT** you should note that options you pass to `xtable` have no effect! Instead you need to pass those options to the 'renderTable' function.

so if you want to call this:

```
output$example <- renderTable({
   table <- someTable_Data_here
   xtable(table, align=c("llr"))
}, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
```

what you need to do is:

```
output$example <- renderTable({
   table <- someTable_Data_here
   table
},align=c("llr"), sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
```

The RStudio team and the RShiny guys are awesome. I'm sure a ton of the documentation is still being written, and I hope this helps someone in the mean time.

Comment: Is there an equivalent of `sanitize.text.function` for `renderDataTable`? Thanks!

Comment: It looks unlikely, as `sanitize.text.function` is from the `xtable` package which itself writes the html - `renderTable` is just passing parameters to it. It _is_ probably possible to embed html in a way that `renderDataTable` will properly display it... but that sounds like a new question!

Comment: You don't need to use any text sensitization for `renderDataTable` - it renders html automatically. You should note thought that the current implementation (Nov 1st 2014) will sort your stylized html alphabetically without escaping the html! I have submitted a bug report for that.