# Active links or buttons in table rows

Tags: r, shiny

I use shiny / R to display a table. I would like to put, on each row of the table, a button or link that would perform some action, passing on the ID or number of the row. I tried the following approach:

```
library( shiny )
tt <- read.table( text="  id      blah       img
1  1      adsf test1.png
2  2      ioiu test2.png
3  3 ioiuoiuer test3.png", stringsAsFactors= F )

runApp( list( 
  ui= basicPage( h3( textOutput( "blah" ) ), dataTableOutput( "view" ) ),
  server= function( input, output ) { 
    output$blah <- renderText({ paste( "action: ", input$load_url1 ) } ) 
    curdata <- reactive({ 
        tmp <- tt ; 
        for( i in 1:nrow( tmp ) ) tmp$img[i] <-  as.character( actionButton( paste0( "load_url", i ), "Load URL" ) )   
        tmp }) 
    output$view <- renderDataTable({ curdata() }) 
  } ) )
```

It does not work. Buttons are rendered, but clicking on them does not influence the view.

Comment: What do you expect the buttons to do? Where is the code to make them do something?

Comment: At the moment, the code just attempts to use the value from the first button (`output$blah <- renderText({ paste( "action: ", input$load_url1 ) } )`).

Comment: Ah. I missed that. I am not sure why load_url1 is NULL even after clicking. Not an answer but ... can you use links or regular buttons rather than action buttons? If you just want to open an image from a url that should be straightforward.

Comment: Well, I could, but it would be more cumbersome: either a second shiny App with the same data which generates the images from a URL, or a link to a static image, pre-generated. None of this is elegant; I'd prefer to have a page that pops up an image when a button (or link, or whatever) is clicked.

Comment: If the images are created dynamically perhaps [parseQueryString](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/parseQueryString) might be an option to use in combination with links.

Comment: Yes, I am just trying that -- but I cannot even get a functional link inside of a table. The renderDataTable results in links that are not functional. The renderTable results in escaped HTML. Do I have to write my own renderTable substitute?

Comment: You could always create the html for a table and embed links. However, take a look at the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019709/r-shiny-table-not-rendering-html) as well (i.e., sanitize.text.function).

Comment: OK, it works now, using links and parseQueryString (had a typo, that is why it didn't work at first). You mind posting an answer? I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using links or regular buttons rather than action buttons. If the images are created dynamically [parseQueryString](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/parseQueryString) might be an option to use in combination with links. You could always create the html for a table and embed links. However, take a look at the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019709/r-shiny-table-not-rendering-html) as well (i.e., sanitize.text.function).