# Render Greek letters in table ouput of shiny apps

Tags: html, r, shiny

My fellow Shiny users! I'm having trouble rendering a Greek letter in my Shiny table output. Notice that I do know how to print a Greek letter in Shiny using the HTML function. See the code snippets below.

This is ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("A sample"),

  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput(
      inputId = "alpha",
      label = HTML("&alpha;:"),
      value = 0.05,
      step = 0.01
    )
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("samplePlot")
  )
))
```

And this is server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$samplePlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(c(1:100), main = "A Sample Plot", xlab = "Whatever")
  })
})
```

This works fine and gives me a Greek alpha in the slider. However, I wish to have Greek letters in my table output as well, but a similar approach doesn't seem to work... See the code below.

This is ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("A sample"),

  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput(
      inputId = "alpha",
      label = HTML("&alpha;:"),
      value = 0.05,
      step = 0.01
    )
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("samplePlot"),
    tableOutput("myTable")
  )
))
```

And this is server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$samplePlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(c(1:100), main = "A Sample Plot", xlab = "Whatever")
  })

  output$myTable <- renderTable({
    data.frame(alpha = HTML("&alpha;:"), value = 3)
  })
})
```

Any ideas on how to get the Greek alpha printed out in the alpha column of the table output. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
sanitize.text.function = function(x) x
```

as an option to renderTable,

the idea which I got from this post:

[r shiny table not rendering html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019709/r-shiny-table-not-rendering-html?rq=1)