# shiny - turn element in output table into link

Tags: shiny

I am building a website to allow users to access some experimental data. I am working in R MarkDown.

I am new to web development and I do not know Javascript, so I have built my *Search* tool as a Shiny app, with the search results presented in form of a table with the result name and a few details.

I want to turn the name into a link to a .rmd document that the user can click to access more details about that result.

```
data=as.matrix(cbind(names=letters[1:10], position=1:10, val=runif(10)),)

ui <- fluidpage(
        sidebarPanel(
             textInput("name",label = "name", value = "")
        )

        mainPanel(tableOutput("res"))
        )

server <- function (input, output) { 
        searchedName=as.character(input$name)
        if (searchedName != "") {
           res.table=subset(data, data$names==searchedName)
        }
        output$res=renderTable({
                res=as.data.frame(cbind(res.table[,1],res.table[,2]))
                colnames(res)=c("name","position")
                return(res)
                }, align="c", colnames = T)
        }
```

I have tried HTML `(paste0("< a href=page.rmd>",  res$name, "< /a>, collapse=""))` and using `tags$a()`, but neither is recognised as html once passed onto the output table.

Comment: the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019709/r-shiny-table-not-rendering-html) should help you, using the `paste0("< a href=page.rmd>", res$name, "< /a>, collapse="")`.

Comment: paste0("< a href=page.rmd>", res$name, "< /a>", collapse="") - typo (i presume) fix

Answer (score 2):

If it is ok for you to use `renderDataTable` instead of `renderTable`, you can:

- turn your names into links using `paste0` or `sprintf`
- use `renderDataTable` with `escape=FALSE`

Note: I made some changes in the code to have the subsetting in a `reactive` out of `renderDataTable`.

---

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

data=as.matrix(cbind(names=letters[1:10], position=1:10, val=runif(10)))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput("name",label = "name", value = "")
  ),

  mainPanel(

    dataTableOutput("res"))
)

server <- function (input, output) { 

  ## function to turn txt into link --------------
  ToLink <- function(txt,link) {
    paste0('<a href=',link,">",txt,'</a>')
  }


  ## form table ---------------------
  res.table <- reactive({
    req(input$name !="") # to make sure input$name in not empty

    res <- data %>% 
      data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F) %>% 
      filter(names==input$name) %>% 
      select(names,position)

    # turn the names into link/s, if more than one value, provide a vector of urls
    res$names <- ToLink(res$names,"https://www.google.com") #Use ur url/s

    return(res)
  })

  ## render datatable -------------------------
  output$res=renderDataTable({

    res.table()

  }, escape = FALSE # make sure escape=FALSE
  )}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: the link given by @NicE solved the problem. Knowing of renderDataTable does however add a lot of information.