# R shiny table not rendering

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make a table using renderTable but it's not rendering on the browser. Here's the ss
@[imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmehI.jpg)

Full table's [code](https://pastebin.com/5Ww4cBMV)

This's the renderTable code:

```
library(shiny)
library(diceR)

output$clustensemble <- renderTable({
#load file
data <- data()

#consensus cluster
cc <- consensus_cluster(data, nk=3, reps=1, algorithms=c("km","hc"), progress=FALSE)
ce <- as.matrix(cc)
tce <- t(ce)
tce })
```

I've tried using

> sanitize.text.function = function(x) x;

but it didn't work, as stated in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019709/r-shiny-table-not-rendering-html/19056859)

I've also tried using renderUI, but instead it generate another error.

The table consist of number and string, but i think that's not the issue.
Still new at this kind of R project, so I didn't know any other solution. What should I do, and what is the cause of this problem? Thanks!

(EDIT)

[Sample data csv](https://pastebin.com/8QdNWuTg)

[ui.R](https://pastebin.com/CEkFMSXq)

[server.R](https://pastebin.com/rqdrfrXN)

[app.R](https://pastebin.com/047rGXag)

Comment: Please provide more code(in R, not HTML) with sample data

Comment: I've added them, please evaluate, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the data that you use and the ui, we can only guess.
Using the example data from `diceR` I am able to print out a table using base `shiny` or `DT`.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(diceR)

data(hgsc)
# Custom distance function
manh <- function(x) {
  stats::dist(x, method = "manhattan")
}
# Custom clustering algorithm
agnes <- function(d, k) {
  return(as.integer(stats::cutree(cluster::agnes(d, diss = TRUE), k)))
}
assign("agnes", agnes, 1)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("tableDT"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  data <- reactive({
    dat <- hgsc[1:10, 1:50]
    cc <- consensus_cluster(dat, reps = 6, algorithms = c("pam", "agnes"),
                            distance = c("euclidean", "manh"), progress = FALSE)
    ce <- as.matrix(cc)
    t(ce)
  })

  output$tableDT <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data()
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I've edited my post, please. I'll try your solution in the meantime

Comment: It's not working, it seems the problem caused by the data. It goes with this error
`Warning in stats::dist(x = x, method = dist) :
  NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: You dont have a `tableOutput` in the ui for `clustensemble` or am I seeing that wrong? I am seeing just a `verbatimTextOutput`, which is the wrong method for a table..