# Add an indication arrow inside DT cell which will show trend for each time period

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I created a shiny app which uses the dataframe below to summarize by `Dealer` showing previous day count of `name` and last 3 days count of `name` based on the fact that we are in the most recent date (`"2020-01-09"`).

Now I want to add to every selected period (cell) an indication arrow which will show the trend  comparatively to the last time period of the same length, so you would calculate the average number of `name` for 3 days for example and then in the background calculate the previous 3 days.Same for the previous day. Arrow would indicate if the displayed is higher or lower. I am working based on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53915234/icons-in-data-table-in-shiny).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)

name<-c("John","John","John","John","John","John","John")
Dealer<-c("ASD","ASD","ASD","ASD","ASD","ASD","ASD")
Date<-c("2020-01-03","2020-01-04","2020-01-05","2020-01-06","2020-01-07","2020-01-08","2020-01-09")
dataset<-data.frame(name,Dealer,Date)

new<-dataset %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  arrange_all %>%
  group_by(Dealer) %>%
  summarise(PreviousDay = sum(Date == last(Date) - 1), 
            PreviousThree = sum(Date %in% (last(Date) - 3) : last(Date)))

new2<-dataset %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  arrange_all %>%
  group_by(Dealer) %>%
  summarise(PreviousDay = sum(Date == last(Date) - 2), 
            PreviousThree = sum(Date %in% (last(Date) - 6) : last(Date)))

total<-rbind(new,new2)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(box(width = 12, solidHeader = TRUE,
               tableOutput("example_table"))
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
                    sidebar,
                    body
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$example_table <- renderTable(total)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I don't really understand the expected output, can you show what values would be in the final table? The table in your post is only made of one row so I don't understand how you can display a trend

Comment: comparatively to the last time period of the same length, so you would calculate the average number of names for3 days for example and then in the background calculate the previous 3 days. Arrow would indicate if the displayed is higher or lower and it should be in the same cell or at last in a new row below.

Comment: okay but, if I understand well, since dealer ```ASD``` had one client per day for the whole period, the evolution per day and per three-day period is zero (because the number of clients does not change), right?

Comment: well normally there will be many combinations between names and Dealers but this is a mock dataset. The thing is to calculate the clients for a period the the clients from the previous same period (3 days) and add an arrow in the cell or in a new row below.

Comment: I think there's a step missing in the minimal code in your post because I don't understand where you compute the evolution in time, but maybe [this page](https://www.littlemissdata.com/blog/prettytables) will help you to put arrows in your table. Note however that it uses the package ```formattable``` and the functions ```formattableOutput``` and ```renderFormattable```

Comment: I have added the logic. I want to compare the 2 rows and add an arrow in first. Could you help with this or should I make a new Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, here's what I did:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)

name<-c("John","John","John","John","John","John","John")
Dealer<-c("ASD","ASD","ASD","ASD","ASD","ASD","ASD")
Date<-c("2020-01-03","2020-01-04","2020-01-05","2020-01-06","2020-01-07","2020-01-08","2020-01-09")
dataset<-data.frame(name,Dealer,Date)

new<-dataset %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  arrange_all %>%
  group_by(Dealer) %>%
  summarise(PreviousDay = sum(Date == last(Date) - 1), 
            PreviousThree = sum(Date %in% (last(Date) - 3) : last(Date))) %>%
  mutate(period = 2)

new2<-dataset %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  arrange_all %>%
  group_by(Dealer) %>%
  summarise(PreviousDay = sum(Date == last(Date) - 2), 
            PreviousThree = sum(Date %in% (last(Date) - 6) : last(Date))) %>%
  mutate(period = 1)

total<-rbind(new,new2) %>%
  arrange(period)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(box(width = 12, solidHeader = TRUE,
               formattableOutput("example_table"))
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
                    sidebar,
                    body
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$example_table <- renderFormattable({
    improvement_formatter <- formatter("span", 
                                       style = x ~ style(font.weight = "bold", 
                                                         color = ifelse(x-lag(x) > 0, "green", 
                                                                        ifelse(x-lag(x) < 0, "red", "black"))), 
                                       x ~ icontext(ifelse(x-lag(x)>0, "arrow-up", 
                                                           ifelse(x-lag(x)<0, "arrow-down", "")), 
                                                    x)
    )
    formattable(total, list(
                `PreviousThree` = improvement_formatter,
                `PreviousDay` = improvement_formatter)
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In `formatter`, I use the sign of `x-lag(x)` to determine the color of the number and the direction of the arrow since you want the evolution between two periods. That requires to create a column period in your final dataframe to determine what is the value of `lag(x)`. If you don't want to display the column `period`, you can put `total[, -4]` instead of `total` in `formattable`.

I don't know if this solution can be generalized easily but at least it is a working basis.

See [here](https://www.littlemissdata.com/blog/prettytables) to customize the `formattable`.

Comment: thanks a lot.may I ask why you added only  `PreviousThree` = improvement_formatter and not something for PreviousDay? Beacuse there may be more than 2 periods that I want to check

Comment: also how can I add the arrow in the 1st line instead of 2nd?

Comment: I edited my post to add ```PreviousDay``` in the ```formattable```. The number of periods isn't really important here. However, it is important that there is a column indicating the time period because the color and the direction of the arrow is determined by the evolution between two periods with ```x-lag(x)```. Therefore, no matter the number of periods as long as there is a time indicator in your dataframe.

Comment: tnx how can I use it 1st row instead of 2nd?

Comment: I don't know that

Comment: I created a new Q