# Add a button next to statement in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to display text in Shiny. But I also need to add a button next to the displayed text.

When when I open the application I can see the plain HTML content (but no button)

Shiny code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Example reactiveValues"),
  
  mainPanel(
    
    # input field
    textInput("user_text", label = "Enter some text:", placeholder = "Please enter some text."),
    actionButton("submit", label = "Submit"),
    
    # display text output
    textOutput("text"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  flag_1 <- TRUE
  
text_reactive = reactiveValues(text = "No values are updated")

output$text <- renderText({
  text_reactive$text
})

observeEvent(input$submit,{
  if(flag_1 <- FALSE)
  {
  text_reactive$text <- input$user_text
  }
  else {
    text_reactive$text <-  paste0("hi", HTML(as.character(actionButton('id','label'))))
  }
})



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there a way to render the HTML code into an actual button?

Comment: did you check with `actionButton()` https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/actionButton.html ? Also this link may help have it inline  https://community.rstudio.com/t/aligning-action-button-next-to-input-box-in-ui-r-shiny/14796

Comment: No Basically i need in the server. For escape, i can paste a button in Dt table buy declaring ````escape = false````. But in a line, how do i paste a button? hope you got my point:)

Comment: `actionButton('id','label')` returns `<button id="id" type="button" class="btn btn-default action-button">label</button>`. You can feed to this structure.

Comment: I did this, But when I open the application I am getting ````hi<button id="id" type="button" class="btn btn-default action-button">label</button>````

Comment: Did you try wrapping it with `HTML()`?

Comment: I tried with ````paste0("hi", HTML(actionButton('id','label')))````. But the application is crashing Error : ````Error in FUN: argument is not a character vector````

Comment: what is your output-render function here?  `renderTable()` has this discussion about `sanitize.text.function` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019709/r-shiny-table-not-rendering-html

Comment: I have edited my question. It is a renderText. I have added my entire application. So, when you write something and click on submit, there should be "Hi" and a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following?

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Example reactiveValues"),
  
  mainPanel(
    # input field
    textInput("user_text", label = "Enter some text:", placeholder = "Please enter some text."),
    actionButton("submit", label = "Submit"),
    
    # display text output
    uiOutput("text"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  flag_1 <- TRUE
  
  text_reactive = reactiveValues(text = "No values are updated")
  
  output$text <- renderUI({
    HTML(text_reactive$text)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$submit,{
    if(flag_1 <- FALSE)
    {
      text_reactive$text <- input$user_text
    }
    else {
      text_reactive$text <-  paste0("hi", HTML(as.character(actionButton('id',input$user_text))))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hey one question. But I am not able to trigger it. Example, I need to pop up the modal box after clicking the button. Can we do it?