# Shiny: How can I create action links in a table based on the data, and then perform a filter using data from the link?

Tags: r, shiny

I have two tables with a shared key.  The first table is always displayed in the UI.  I would like the user to be able to click a link in the table and then show a modal dialogue that is the second table filtered based on the link that was clicked.

Specific example: Show `mtcars` as a table, with clickable links for the `gear` column.  When one is clicked, for instance a `4`, a modal dialog appears that shows all the cars with 4 gears.  If `3` was clicked, you'd get all cars with 3 gears.

It does not appear that there is anyway to pass an argument with `shiny::actionLink()`, which is what I assume I would want to use for the table links.  I realize my example below does not correctly create the links, but without knowing how the 2nd step works (acting on the links) I've just left in some pseudo code as an example.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("mtcars"),

        mainPanel(
           tableOutput("table")
        )
    )


server <- function(input, output) {

    output$table <- renderTable({
        mtcars %>% 
            mutate(gear = actionLink("gearinput", label = gear)) #I realize this does not work, just leaving here as pseudo code.
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$gearinput, {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Gear filter",
        mtcars %>% filter(gear == input$gearinput)), #I can't figure out how to actually get the value based on the link clicked
      )
    })
     
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with `dplyr` so I switched to `data.table`.

We can add an onclick event to the `actionLinks` and provide the clicked gear to shiny via `Shiny.setInputValue`:

```
library(shiny)
# library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

DT <- copy(mtcars)
setDT(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("mtcars"),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    DT[, inputId := paste0("gear_input_", seq_len(.N))][, gear_links := as.character(actionLink(inputId = inputId, label = inputId, onclick = sprintf("Shiny.setInputValue(id = 'gear_click', value = %s);", gear))), by = inputId][, inputId := NULL]
  }, sanitize.text.function = function(x){x})
  
  observeEvent(input$gear_click, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Gear filter",
      tableOutput("filtered_table"),
      size = "xl"
    ))
  })
  
  output$filtered_table <- renderTable({
    req(input$gear_click)
    DT[gear == input$gear_click][, c("gear_links", "vs") := NULL]
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: result]

You might want to change the labels of the links to `gear` - but this way it's more comprehensible.

Useful links regarding this:

[r shiny table not rendering html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019709/r-shiny-table-not-rendering-html)

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html

Comment: So beautiful :')